# Can I use "comment-column" for comments in other modes than emacs-lisp-mode?

Tags: indentation, comment

Emacs-lisp-mode distinguishes multiple kinds of comments.

- `;` is an "end of line" comment when following code, or a "right-margin" comment obeying `comment-column` when indented with `indent-for-tab-command`. This style is partcilularly useful for commenting on a code detail, since the indentation and alignment deemphasizes the comment.
- `;;` will be aligned with the indentation of surrounding code and is especially useful as a header of code sections or for longer comment text, where necessary.

I haven't seen this distinction in other modes; `indent-for-comment` (<kbd>M-;</kbd>) will happily indent to `comment-column` for end-of-line comments, but comments on their own line seem to be indented like `;;`, not like `;`.

Is there some way to make emacs allow `;` style indentation also for other modes, such as shell-script-mode?

```
if [ $THIS_IS = $A_CODE_LINE ]; then
                           # I want to be able to comment
                           # on the right-side margin
    ## and inline with
    the code
fi
```

Comment: clojure-mode uses this feature, I think it is unique to linting in lisps.